# How do I set Highcharts categories dynamically?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been reading through the documentation and googling for hours and have not made any progress on finding these categories. I am building the grapg.

```
var udsChart; //global UDS chart variable
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getJsonData.aspx?ID=udsLevel1',
        success: function (point) {
            udsChart.series[0].setData(point, true);
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);                
        },
        cache: false
    });
}

udsChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'udsGraphDiv',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        text: 'xAxis'
    },
    yAxis: {
        text: 'yAxis'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: []
    }]
});
```

[image]

Comment: try making your response param something else instead of point , means  success: function (myData) {

 
    var udsChart = $("#udsGraphDiv").Highcharts(); 
    udsChart.series[0].setData(myData, true);  Also share your data format ,is this a array with string and values? post response of ajax here to debug it better.

Comment: it's a jSon object. Just two  values

[["01/22/2016",108],["01/24/2016",45],["01/25/2016",261],["01/26/2016",224],["01/27/2016",307],["01/28/2016",64]]

Comment: You need to set categories and data separately for column chart. iterate over the data and push dates in category and values in series.data For example  var data = {"name":"someName","data":[50,,150,155,324,705]}; and 
    var categories = [5600, 5700,5800,5900,6000,6100];

Comment: I understand that, I was able to do it on a regular graph but I cannot figure out where and how to place the code in the live chart.

Comment: Adding code for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to set xAxis category property.
Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulson/p5debep6/1/).

```
var data = [["01/22/2016",108],["01/24/2016",45],["01/25/2016",261],
["01/26/2016",224],["01/27/2016",307],["01/28/2016",64]];

var cat = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {

  cat.push(item[0]);

});

udsChart = new Highcharts.Chart({


chart: {
    renderTo: 'udsGraphDiv',
    defaultSeriesType: 'column',
    events: {
        //load: requestData
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
},
xAxis: {
    text: 'xAxis',
    categories: cat
},
yAxis: {
    text: 'yAxis'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: data 
}]

});
```

Comment: Nice. Another way of solving this is documented here: https://blueflame-software.com/how-to-create-dynamic-x-axis-data-using-json/

Answer (score 8):

Either your categories should fixed and you can setData via setData function with array of values. But if categories also changing , try this

```
 success: function (data) {
 var categories= [];
 var seriesData = [];
 $.each(data,function(item){
      categories.push(item[0]);
      seriesData.push(item[1]);
 });
 udsChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories); //setting category
 udsChart.series[0].setData(seriesData , true); //setting data
setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Will try this and report back.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing simple property: [`xAxis.type`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type). Set it to `category` and will work, like this:

```
xAxis: {
    text: 'xAxis',
    type: 'category'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
udsChart.xAxis["categories"] = ['a','b','c']
```